# double sum $\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sqrt{j^2+k^2} z^{j+k}$

Tags: calculus

I am interesting in the real zeros of the function:
$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sqrt{j^2+k^2} z^{j+k}$$
looking where change the value but it is hard to compute , using Mathematica
$$\text{NSum}\left[(-1)^{j+k} \sqrt{j^2+k^2},\{j,1,\infty \},\{k,1,\infty \},\text{WorkingPrecision}\to 20\right]$$ gives ComplexInfinity, but i think it is not true cause the values is 0.14540 aproximately calculate with maple use Levin Transform this method it is capable to calculate to -3 to -1, using a double transform I have been calculating the following values
[image]
and for the z =1 need a  condensation alternative series and gives the values 0.0137496275139485217544804966782611 it is must be to reals zeros between -4 and -3 and 1 and 2
it is possible to get the same result with other methods??

Comment: Well, Mathematica did nothing wrong because the sum diverges when $|z|\geq 1$. I don't know much about series acceleration, but note that the accelerated series can converge even if the original one doesn't.

Comment: @SangchulLee being generous, it seems like analytic continuation (or the antilimit as is the more general terminology in numerical analysis) would be the way forward to analyze the function for zeros outside of its given ROC. But finding a closed form has not been easy either :/

Comment: @NinadMunshi, Glad that I've learned the word *antilimit*. I also suspect some analytic continuation stuff is going on here, and tried to simplify the sum as $$\sum_{j,k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{j^2+k^2}z^{j+k}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\Psi(z,1)^2-\Psi(z,t)^2}{t^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ where $|z| < 1$ and $$\Psi(z,t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}z^k e^{-k^2 t}. $$ This function seems related to Jacobi theta functions, but honestly I have little background on them, so I can't see if this helps or not...

Comment: @Sangchul Lee this is great but the integral have a pole near to 0 change the limit you could get consistent values ​​but it is very difficult to get exact values $$\left(\text{LL}=\left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } e^{-k^2} z^k\text{/.}\, z\to -1\right)-\left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } e^{k^2 (-t)} z^k\text{/.}\, z\to -1\right)\right) \text{NIntegrate}\left[\frac{\text{LL}}{\left(2 \sqrt{\pi }\right) t^{3/2}},\{t,1,\infty \}\right]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using $$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{\left(j^2+k^2\right)^s}=2^{-2 s} \left(2^{2 s}-2\right) \zeta (2 s)-2^{-3 s} \left(2^s-2\right) \zeta (s) \left(\zeta \left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta \left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)$$ formula from Wolfram world takins s=-1/2 is equal to 0.145403 ==$$1/4 - 2 Sqrt[
  2] (-2 + 1/Sqrt[2]) Zeta[-(1/2)] (Zeta[-(1/2), 1/4] - 
    Zeta[-(1/2), 3/4])$$ agree with the above result , the rest it is impossible to calculate at the moment